# how to use scrollIt.js in different sections of the page with different topOffset?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I need your help please.

Can i use different topOffset in different sections of the page ?

For example;

for the "About me" and "Portfolio" sections :

```js
$(function(){
    $.scrollIt({
        scrollTime: 3000,
        topOffset: -80,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
});
```

for the "Certification" section :

```js
$(function(){
    $.scrollIt({
        scrollTime: 3000,
        topOffset: 40,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code? On an event somewhere? If so can you show *that* code also

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.
This is isotope librairy.
[You can show code here](https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.js)

```html
<li><a href="#" data-scroll-nav="1">About Me</a></li>
```

send us here

```html
-> <!-- ====== ABOUT ME ====== -->
        <section data-scroll-index="1" class="section_about_me">
```

I'm sorry, i don't explain very well.

```html
<header data-scroll-index="0">
        <div class="navbarr">
            <i class="fas fa-bars ban" id="burger"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll-nav="0">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll-nav="1">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll-nav="2">Certification</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll-nav="3">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll-nav="4">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="firstdiv">
            <h1>Hi Bro !!!</h1>
            <p class="ban1"><span>Je suis</span> <span class="ban2"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="logo_social">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- ====== ABOUT ME ====== -->
    <section data-scroll-index="1" class="section_about_me">
        <div class="about_me">
            <h1>About me</h1>
            <h2>Directeur de la commission de recherche à la Goliath National Bank</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="fullscreen_about_me">
            <div class="photo_barney">
                <img src="images/barney.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="text_about_me">
                <p>Je suis un homme d'une trentaine d'années vivant à New York
                    Je travaille comme directeur de la commission de recherche à la Goliath National Bank,
                    La plus en vue et la plus surprenante des banques de cette nation.
                    Depuis de nombreuses années, je vis en suivant les règles du “Bro Code“,
                    mes propres règles de vie qui devrait être appliqué à chaque bro de cette nation.</p>

                <div class="skill_container">
                    <div class="skill1">
                        <p>Menteur</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="skill_container">
                    <div class="skill2">
                        <p>Laser Tag</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="skill_container">
                    <div class="skill3">
                        <p>Magie</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="download_contact">
                    <button class="button_download_contact1">Download CV</button>
                    <button class="button_download_contact2">Contact Me</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```